# Complex objects in chatGPT function calling arguments

Tags: openai-api

I wanted to prompt chatGPT to return an array of  JSON object as arguments as part of the function calling feature. However I do not see how we can specify the object description
E.g.

```
functions = 

[
    {
        "name": "get_ICD_codes",
        "description": "Get the ICD codes with description in the  given format",
        "parameters": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "icds": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "description": "Array of ICD objects",
                     "items": {
                            **"type": "object",**
                            "description": "An object with Icd code and description as properties"
                        },

                }
            },
            "required": ["icds"],
        },
    }
]
```

where icds is an array of '`icd_obj`' objects . The '`icd_obj`' consists of 2 properties code and description

How can we specify object and define the above properties in the highlighted type field?

I tried using the above syntax and description but it does not work. I could not find any documentation on openAI reference docs as well.

Comment: Have able to solve that problem?

Answer (score -1):

Chat GPT will only return text format. The code you are citing is not the function itself, it is the way of calling the function, and where you provide the parameters requiered. those parameters are the one that chatGPT will try to get from the conversation. The function itself is the one than will return a JSON object:

```
def get_ICD_codes(parameter1, paremeter2, ...):
   # do something
   icd_objects = {
       "object_1":
           {
              "code": "code_1",
              "description": "description_1",
           },
       "object_2":
           {
              "code": "code_2",
              "description": "description_2",
           },
   }
 
   return json.dumps(icd_objects)
```